# Is there an API to replace a range of values in a list by another list?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a current list that I wish to update by replacing a range of elements by another list, For example:

CurrentList:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g
```

NewList:

```
x, y, z
```

I would like to do something similar to the following:

```
CurrentList.setAll(5, NewList)
```

Which should transform the `CurrentList` to have the following values:

```
a, b, c, d, e, x, y, z
```

So it replaced the `f, g` elements by `x, y` and also `added` the `CurrentList` an extra new `z`.

EDIT: This is not always on the end of the list. And its not only about strings. It's about a list having any type of elements. This needs to work on any portion of the list. For example I may need to replace `b, c, d`. I simply have the starting index and then I have to replace elements onward and if the list is out of space, then `add` to list instead of replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is this :

```
List<?> list = ...  // original list
List<?> toReplace = list.subList(startingIndex, endIndex);
toReplace.clear(); // clears the subList
List<?> replacement = ... // list of new elements
toReplace.addAll(replacement); // inserts the new elements in the original list, through the sublist
```

You can also add your new elements one by one. The backing List will grow in size as needed.

Comment: but this assumes that the `endIndex` will never exceed the original list's size. I'm asking if this can be done in one statement by providing the `startingIndex` and the list with the elements to replace.

Comment: it does not assume that, the endIndex is the end index of *the subList to replace*. The resulting subList will be able to shrink and grow as needed as well. I don't think this can be done 'in one statement' with the List API

Answer (score 4):

If you have a collection of letters you are better off using a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abcdefg");
sb.replace(5, sb.length(), "xyz");
```

If you have a List of elements you can do

```
List<String> list = ...
List<String> subList = list.subList(5, list.size());
subList.clear();
subList.addAll(Arrays.asList("x", "y", "z"));
```

Comment: @durron597 That does the same thing but is closer to what the OP asked for.

Comment: If you keep a reference to the sublist, and add to it after clear(), it will even work when the range is not at the end of the list.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. This list is not about strings only, it may hold any type of elements. Thank you for your solution but this will only work if I'm adding\replacing at the end of the list which may not always be the case. I need to be able to replace any portion of the target list whether it's in the middle or the end , regardless of how much size is left in it too. Thanks again.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana bowmore suggested the solution, which I included.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, your solution assumes that the list with the new element s will either exceed or meet the original list's last element. I'm asking if, in one statement, I can replace the elements of a list, starting at an index, stopping when the last element of the new list is set and increasing the original list's size only if needed.